# HTML5 Video not working in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: html, video

I am using this snippet below.  The video works when clicked in safari but it doesn't work when clicked in firefox, ie, and chrome.

Snippet:

```
      <video width="560" height="340" controls>
      <source src="/media/intro.mp4" type='video/mp4; 
      codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
      </video>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html5 - mp4 video does not play in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944679/html5-mp4-video-does-not-play-in-ie9)

Answer (score 6):

You need to convert your mp4 video to ogv and include it as a source. It also may be a good idea to include a webm version of the video.

You can use this program to convert it.
Windows only, [XMedia Recode](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/XMedia-Recode)

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls="controls">
      <source src="media/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      <source src="media/intro.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
      <source src="media/intro.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```