# HTML5 Video not working in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: html, email, html5-video

I can't seem to get the following HTML5 Video code working, am I missing something.

```
<video width="267" poster="Poster.gif" height="209">
<source src="6Minutes_1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
<source src="6Minutes_1.ogg" type="video/ogg"></source>
<source src="6Minutes_1.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
<a href="http://$$__cm_domain$$/r/mail/$$mailid$$"><img style="display: block;" src="Poster.gif" alt="" /></a>
</video>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies my question was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13585801/1454869 - I was missing a controls element.