# how to disable gzip compression for mp4

Tags: wordpress, gzip, mp4

I am trying to stop gzip compression on my wordpress blog because if i post a mp4 video even with using the software qtindexswapper it still loads the whole thing before i can play it. I have tried all kinds of different code in my .htaccess file to disable gzip but it just doesnt work. Any ideas?

For example here is some of the code i have tried in my .htaccess where the videos are stored

SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .mp4$ no-gzip dont-vary

Answer (score 3):

Do you try ?

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp4$ no-gzip dont-vary## Heading ##
```

And see: [How to disable Apache gzip compression for some media files in .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249243/how-to-disable-apache-gzip-compression-for-some-media-files-in-htaccess-file)

Comment: Thanks - this was a lifesaver. There is an issue with cloudflare not resolving mp4s in safari. this did the trick

Comment: You are a life saver, I have this same issue with cloudflare, Now resolved. Thanks!