# HTTP Header Content-Length not work

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mod-deflate

I wish to display the size of the file to the client when they download it.
But HTTP Header Content-Length not work.
My Environment is follow.

- Apache 2.2
- mod_deflate
- Rails3.2

A download file is in the rails project public folder.

Response Header is this when I download it.

> Accept-Ranges bytes
>   Access-Control-Allow-Head...    origin, x-requested-with, content-type
>   Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
>   Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    http://*****.com
>   Connection  Keep-Alive
>   Content-Encoding    gzip
>   Content-Type    application/octet-stream
>   Date    Fri, 14 Dec 2012 05:15:09 GMT
>   Etag    "c1bcc-1c828800-4d0a3ac0f7389"
>   Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
>   Last-Modified   Wed, 12 Dec 2012 08:34:51 GMT
>   Server  Apache
>   Transfer-Encoding   chunked
>   Vary    Accept-Encoding

Is there any way to display the Content-Length?

Comment: If I disable the mod_deflate, Content-Length is displayed.Why?

Comment: Content-Length is displayed when it is small file. I think that buffer is not enough.

Comment: The problem was solved.
I changed the setting of the apache, from using un-compressed file to using the pre-compressed file.

Comment: how did you do that? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old thread, it is a problem related to gzip compression.
For others reading this question, here is my solution, based on this thread:

[How to disable Apache gzip compression for some media files in .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249243/how-to-disable-apache-gzip-compression-for-some-media-files-in-htaccess-file)

You can add the following rule to your .htaccess

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|png|pdf|xxx)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

if you want to disable compression for certain file types or

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI (url_to_not_compress) no-gzip dont-vary
```

if you have a script that forces a file to download.