# JMeter - Disallow gzipped content while recording

Tags: jmeter, gzip, recording

I'm attempting to record a standalone Java program which communicates with a backend server through HTTP.
While it's no problem to pipe the communication through a Jmeter proxy the content that i'm seeing (in my recording) is gzipped which makes it impossible to read (and adapt).

Is there any way to force JMeter to unzip the content while recording?
My response data is fine (unzipped/plain json) but it's the POST data that is being sent that is unreadable.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: hard to say without seeing it, but likely it's a setting on the server side, rather than JMeter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249243/how-to-disable-apache-gzip-compression-for-some-media-files-in-htaccess-file for example

Comment: Sadly since it's a standalone application which only communicates through http I'm unable to change the setting for "sending" without a code change. I've been able to get samples from the developers however so I'm able to continue now. However If anyone has a solution for this directly in JMeter I would be very interrested for future use cases.