# Trouble rendering Html5 video in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

Could anyone tell me why the videos, under the 'MockUps' section of the following website will work in chrome but not in IE9?

I have used html5 to implement the videos

http://homepages.shu.ac.uk/~a8025613/Index.html

A video element is coded like this:

```
<video id=0 controls width=320 height=240>
<source src="House_1/House_1.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
<source src="House_1/House_1.webm" type='video/webm' >
<source src="House_1/House_1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<p>Video is not visible, most likely your browser does not support HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```

Comment: They don't display in my Chrome either, probably because of your `#MockUp { display:none } rule.

Comment: @ChrisW they appear with jquery when the link "mockUp" is clicked

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 - mp4 video does not play in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944679/html5-mp4-video-does-not-play-in-ie9)