# html5 video mp4 works in safari but not ie9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, safari, internet-explorer-9

I'm having an issue with ie9 and mp4 videos. If I open the page in Safari the mp4 videos work fine but they won't load in ie9. I'm out of ideas as to what it might be.

On my local windows machine the html5 videos play fine, once the pages go to the live server they no longer work. Opera and Firefox are working fine with the OGG format. Safari plays the .mp4 format but IE will not. Internet explorer is the only browser that is acting odd.

I thought it was a Mime Type issue except that Safari works with the server side .mp4 file.

Iv looked into it being a Doctype issue, except the doctype on the live site is the same as it is on my local. I'm running out of ideas as to what could be causing this.

```
          <video webkitSupportsFullscreen='false' width="960" height="640">
            <source id="mp4" src="/videos/video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            <source src="/video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
            <source src="/video/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <img src="/images/screenshot.jpg">
        </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML5 Please](http://html5please.com/#video) recommand using a polyfill for this.

So you can use this one : http://mediaelementjs.com/

**Note:** Are you sure your DOCTYPE respect the HTML5 syntax as following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I'm not using the html5 tag. I updated description to explain the situation better.

Comment: Maybe this topic can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944679/html5-mp4-video-does-not-play-in-ie9

Comment: the doctype isn't html5 in mine but it still works locally. I'm confused because it works locally but not remotely so i'm not sure if IE9 is cqching something or some such.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `<!doctype html>` defination? If it's not, IE9 will run in quirks mode that has no html5 support.

Comment: there is no <!doctype html> in the page but the video loads on my local environment, just no the live site.

Comment: What I think is you better add that back because it'll solve many problem with HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the meta tag for the X-UA-Compatibility for IE ANYTHING!

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
```