# Autoplay HTML5 Video without Audio track in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, internet-explorer-9

I'm having trouble making an MP4 video autoplay in my HTML5 page in IE9.

From reading other stack [overflow posts on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944679/html5-mp4-video-does-not-play-in-ie9/10739821#10739821) I know that it *should* autoplay, especially as I've already used `qt-faststart` on the video to move the file info to the headers, but all I'm getting is the fallback image when I look at the page in IE9 (XP).

I'm wondering if the fact that there is no audio track at all on the video could be causing IE9 to not want to autostart it? Wouldn't be the quirkiest thing IE had ever done...

The code for my video element is as follows:

```
<video autoplay loop preload width="1200" height="510" poster="/path/to/header-video-poster.png" class="hero__subsection__image">
  <source src="/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <img src="/path/to/header-video-poster.png" alt="Fallback">
</video>
```

Comment: Does the video play at all on IE9?