# Wrapping HTML5 videos with links - controls does not work on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I want to wrap the HTML5 video with link tag:

```html
<a href="yourpage.html">
  <video width="560" height="315" autoplay muted controls loop>
       <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
   </video>
</a>
```

It works perfectly on Chrome and Opera - I can click on the controls, eg, pause, play, volume, etc. And I also can click on the link that I want to go to another page when you click on it.

But it does not work on Firefox at all - I can't **only** click on the controls. It triggers the link **too** when I click anything on the controls! I want it to work the same way as Chrome/ Opera.

Any ideas how I can fix this on Firefox?

Comment: Seems like Firefox is doing what it's supposed to. By putting an element within an anchor, clicking anywhere on that element should trigger the anchor's default behavior (navigating to the `href`).

Comment: IE used to be the pain in the a** for us. Now finally Firefox is catching up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May the Solution is being in updating Firefox? I dont know which version u are using, but the TAG `<video>` is new in html5 (may you alread know that) and not all version of browsers accept them. Else i would say it is a bug in Firefox itselfs, not a mistake in your code.

On W3Schools there is a list wich version you need: [klick me](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

> Added VideoJS link

Otherways use [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/), an openSource video player

Comment: I'm on 51.0.1 (64-bit) and Ubuntu.

Comment: I´ve no other idea @teelou. 
May you can use [link](http://videojs.com/) like someone got the same problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944679/html5-mp4-video-does-not-play-in-ie9)

Comment: No problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use an iframe:

```
 <a href="yourpage.html">
   <iframe src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"></iframe> 
 </a>
```

I think that is better for Firefox and for anothers too.