# What's the most supported video extension for modern browsers?

Tags: html5-video

I'm in the process of making some animated UI videos for my portfolio (which is going bad as hell, since there is no transparency support & colors in the export are wrong..), but I'm unsure which format I should export to.

I can do mp4, mov, etc. But what is the best one with support for IE9+ and Chrome for the past years, i.e. the modern versions ever since Windows 7? I assume support with Safari & Mac is already very up to date..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All major browsers support H.264 video. IE 9+ supports MP4, but not WebM unfortunately.

There is more information in this SO thread that includes some workarounds.

[HTML5 - mp4 video does not play in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944679/html5-mp4-video-does-not-play-in-ie9)

Comment: Yes it is. WebM is often H.264 as well, but IE won't support it for whatever reason.